# Is there a do-while loop in bash?

Tags: bash

Is there a `do`-`while` loop in bash?

I know how to program a `while` loop in bash:

```
while [[ condition ]]; do
    body
done
```

Is there a similar construct, but for a `do`-`while` loop, where the `body` is executed at least once irrespective of the `while` condition?

Comment: How hard would it have been to read through the list of bash built-ins in the man page and see if any of them were do-while?

Comment: @Barmar It's a lot harder to look for something that isn't there than something that is.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`while` loops are flexible enough to also serve as `do-while` loops:

```
while 
  body
  condition
do true; done
```

For example, to ask for input and loop until it's an integer, you can use:

```
while
  echo "Enter number: "
  read n
  [[ -z $n || $n == *[^0-9]* ]]
do true; done
```

This is even better than normal `do-while` loops, because you can have commands that are only executed *after* the first iteration: replace `true` with `echo "Please enter a valid number"`.

Comment: +1. But `do :; done` is a better noop

Comment: It's the same noop written differently.

Comment: I stand corrected. In bash, at least, they are synonyms.

Comment: I would like to point out that using this form, if you are relying on `set -e` to abort the script if any individual line fails, bash will NOT abort for lines in the `body` section! It is therefore better to use the form in @Barmar's answer.

Comment: @BenXO Probably better not to use `set -e` and do your own error detection.

Answer (score 20):

No, there's no `do-while` operator in `bash`. You can emulate it with:

```
while true; do
    body
    [[ condition ]] || break
done
```

Comment: Even though the accepted answer suggests that there is in fact a way to write do-while loops in bash, I would still do it this way as this way obeys `set -e` and the accepted answer's way does not appear to.

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to try this instead, i don't believe there is such a thing in bash.

```
doStuff(){
  // first "iteration" here
}
doStuff
while [condition]; do
  doStuff
done
```

Comment: The function body is never executed if not called outside the loop.

Comment: fixed code to call the function first.